# IOS Detect call interruption while streaming video

Tags: ios, callback, call, avplayer

I'm streaming video using AVPlayer and i want to pause the video when GSM call comes and resume when the call will end and control is back to my app. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, i did it by using `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification`. Below is code snippet

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(routeInterrypt:) name:AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification object:nil];


-(void)routeInterrypt:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *dic = notification.userInfo;
    int changeReason= [dic[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] intValue];
    if (changeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonUnknown) {
        if (_state == TYVideoPlayerStateContentPlaying || _state == TYVideoPlayerStateBuffering) {
            [self pauseContent];
            return;
        }
    } }
```